# bytes convert to float (php)

Tags: php, floating-point, byte

How can I convert from bytes to float in php? Like in Java

```
int i = (byte3 & 0xff) << 24 | (byte2 & 0xff) << 16 | (byte1 & 0xff) << 8 | byte0 & 0xff; 
Float.intBitsToFloat(i);
```

Comment: Can you give an example of how you expect that bytes are converted to float?

Comment: do you mean convert int to float?

Comment: Example:

it's bytes:
 1059760811
Must be in float
 0.6666667

Comment: 1059760811 is not by any definition a byte number. Bytes range from 0-255.

Comment: How can i remade:
 int i = (byte3 & 0xff) << 24 | (byte2 & 0xff) << 16 | (byte1 & 0xff) << 8 | byte0 & 0xff;
 Float.intBitsToFloat(i);

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There may be a more direct way, but here you go:

```
<?php
var_dump(unpack('f', pack('i', 1059760811)));
?>
```

This is, of course, machine dependent, but I don't know of any machine running PHP that doesn't use IEEE 754 floats.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think php has bytes, does it?
When you assign a number to a variable you'll get an variable with a number type

```
$a = 10; // integer
$f = 1.0; // double
$b = $a + $f; // $b is double
```

Comment: yes php not have bytes system. but i have to make from bytes to float.

it's bytes: 1059760811 > 0.6666667 (float)

Comment: out of interest, which programming language does have the *byte* variable type?

Comment: I have remade one script form java to php. it will be last task.
In java it easy: Float.intBitsToFloat(integer);

Comment: @MatW: Strangely enough, Java and C# have a byte variable type... but it's just a 1 byte unsigned number type (values 0-255).

Comment: Valdas, that's an integet to a float. I don't get how you get 2/3rd from that integer though..

Comment: Incidentally, Float.intBitsToFloat is described here: http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#intBitsToFloat%28int%29

Comment: I dont know in JAVA i checked. In php manual:  For instance, 1/3 in decimal form becomes 0.3.

Comment: @OMG Unicorns Thx +1. If I could give you extra for the username, I would!

Comment: @MatW: Ha, I changed it for April Fools Day, but can't change it back until May 1st. :D

Comment: Ah, now I understand what you are trying to do ^^

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you want to take a raw 32- or 64-bit "integer" value, and force that set of bits to treated as a floating point number instead?

Try the '[pack](http://php.net/pack)' and '[unpack](http://php.net/pack)' functions